# Session concurrency issues with multiple tabs causing Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, concurrency, redis, csrf-token

I have an e-commerce app running on Rails 5.1.5 with `redis-session-store`, but there seems to be a concurrency issue with the sessions when I open more than 1 tab at the same time.

Here's an example on how to reproduce the issue:

- Imagine you either have never accessed the app, or you just cleared the cookies;
- Then you open 2 links on other tabs pretty fast, so the second tab is open before the first one completes the request;
- Now in one of the tabs you have an invalid CSRF-token. And there's no way to tell which one it is.

From what I've seen so far, it seems the server does assign each request a different session_id, one overriding the other, as you can see in the reproduction below:

```
# first request
method=GET path=/my-url format=html controller=ProductsController action=show status=200 session=8cb3c8e8481f4e04772b5d77125132df

# second request
method=GET path=/other-url format=html controller=ProductsController action=show status=200 session=da126c627467fb5e2ab8be9e82c22b85

# notice the different session ids
```

This session information is, of course, added to lograge payload like so:

```rb
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb

  def append_info_to_payload(payload)
    super
    payload[:session] = request.session_options[:id] rescue ""
  end
```

After that, one of the tabs will have an invalid csrf-token and that's going to cause really awkward problems, because since the Add to Cart buttons are all `method: :post, remote: true` buttons, when users try to add a product to their carts, they'll actually wind up in an empty cart page due to rails invalidating the user session when a `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.` happens.

Any thoughts?

**Edit:**

By inspecting the Cookies in Chrome dev tools, I can tell that both tabs share the same session_id, as anyone would expect. **So this problem is only related to the CSRF-token that's generated before the session_id gets overriden.**